# How can solve database query value by ajax that shown in html tag not to be empty value when call for use

Tags: html, jquery

I try to compare balance value that query from database by laravel jquery ajax.
this balance value need to compare with total value,
this total value get from input value.
here is form

```
<form>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                          <label for="">Price</label>
                          <input type="text" id="price" required class="price form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                          <label for="">Amount</label>
                          <input type="text" id="amount" required class="amount form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                          <label for="">Total</label>
                          <input type="text" id="total" required class="total form-control" readonly />
                          <div id="balance" class="form-text">Avaliable Balance<p id="bala"></p></div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" id="btnn" class="btn btn-primary marketbuy">Buy</button>
                      </form>
```

I have this jquery codes. this code make dynamically set total input value by calculating inputed amount value and price value.

I have also this jquery code , this code append balance value to p tag below total input form that get from database .

```
 marketbuyshow();

function marketbuyshow(){

  $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/showmarketbuydata",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (response) {

          
           
            $('#bala').html("");
            $.each(response.balancedata,function(key,item){
                      $('#bala').append('<p>'+item.mybalance+'</p>');
                      
            });
```

My plan is whenever amount is inserted into Amount input and auto calculate total value in Total Input , After that this total value should compare with balance value in p tag that get from database.

if total value is more than avaliable balance , buy button will disable.

```
 let balan = $("#bala").val();
       console.log(balan);

       if($('#total').val()>balan){
        
         $("#btnn").attr("disabled", true);
       }else{
       // console.log("total is less than ");
        $("#btnn").attr("disabled", false);
       }
```

But this p tag value is dynamically get from database , I cannot compare ,
value not show in p tag when I compare with balance value although it show in frontend.
please help me how can do this compare

Comment: `.val()` is for inputs. Use `.text()` for a `<p>`.

Comment: There's no number in the `bala` element. What integer are you expecting to get?

Comment: Given your comments on the answer below - is the `#bala` element's content loaded dynamically, eg. from AJAX?

Comment: edited please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to put a number inside the p tag,

`$("#bala")` returns a jquery object you need to access its first element and the tap into its innerHTML

```js
let balan = $("#bala")[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: still show Nan, not get integer

Comment: If you're using jQuery, use its method: `.text()` or `.html()`

Comment: `$("#bala")` returns a jQuery collection. It's not an array, although it supports indexing.

Comment: @leon I just tried again it is not giving an NaN. You should try console logging just ```$("#bala")``` and see what it gives

Comment: still Nan,not get result

Comment: @leon what does ```$("#bala")``` logs please add the output in the question

Comment: ```Object { 0: p#bala
, length: 1 }
​
0: <p id="bala">
​
length: 1```

Comment: @leon then my code should definetly work, please see again that you copied it perfectly.

Comment: @leon why havent you put anything inside your p tag in the question? it is empty

Comment: it show empty string.

Comment: ``` let balan = $("#bala")[0].innerHTML;
       console.log(balan);  console.log(balan);```

Comment: @leon thats the reason leon you are tring to convert a empty string to an integer and javascript is telling you NaN (not a number)

Comment: I append this value from database to this p tag by jquery ```$('#bala').html("");
            $.each(response.balancedata,function(key,item){
                      $('#bala').append('<p>'+item.mybalance+'</p>');
                      
            });```. So this value not get in this html tag in real time?

Comment: @leon this is important stuff can you elaborate more and add the code snippet so that we can reproduce the problem. Add it in the question itself.

Comment: edited , plz check